# Sums Involving the Mobius Function

Tags: summation, special-functions, analytic-number-theory

Are there any good approximations for the following sums in terms of $n$? 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(k)$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(k)\log^m(k)$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}.$$ I realize that the third sum goes to $0$, I just don't know how fast. Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function

Answer (score 4):

We can prove that the first and second sums grow slower than $n/(\log n)^A$ for any constant $A$, and the third sum is eventually smaller than $1/(\log n)^A$.

The Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the first and second sums growing slower than $n^{1/2+\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, and to the third sum being eventually smaller than $1/n^{1/2-\varepsilon}$. These exponents $1/2$ would be best possible.

Comment: Do you know anything (article, book) about these equivalences to the RH?

Comment: Montgomery and Vaughan's *Multiplicative Number Theory I*, or another graduate-level textbook on analytic number theory, should have what you're looking for. I wouldn't be surprised if Terry Tao had written about it on his blog.